# How can I implement the behavior of unique in matlab using C++?

Tags: c++, matlab, c++11, stl, iterator

In Matlab, the `[C, ia, ic] = unique(A)` function returns an sorted array `C` in which the duplicates in `A` are removed, and the `ia` and `ic` arrays contains the indices such that `C = A(ia) and A = C(ic)`. For example:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, -1, -2, 0, 0, 0, 4]; 
[C, ia, ic] = unique(A); 
C = [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]; 
% The indices are incremented by 1 to accomodate the C++ convection.
ia = [4, 3, 7, 0, 1, 2, 8]; % size(ia) = size(C) 
ic = [3, 4, 5, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 6]; % size(ic) = size(A)
```

Here is my implementation:

```
  std::vector<int> A = {1, 2, 3, -1, -2, 0, 0, 0, 4};
  std::set<int> C(A.begin(), A.end());

  std::vector<int> ic;
  ic.reserve(A.size());

  std::transform(A.begin(), A.end(), std::back_inserter(ic),
                 [&](int x) { return (std::distance(C.begin(), C.find(x))); });
```

I now can correctly get the array C and ic, but I don't know how to get the array ia.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is very similar to how you calculate `ic`. Just swap `A` and `C` in the `transform` call:

```
std::vector<int> ia;
ia.reserve(C.size());

std::transform(C.begin(), C.end(), 
               std::back_inserter(ia),
               [&](int x) { return std::distance(A.begin(), 
                                     std::find(A.begin(), A.end(), x)); 
});
```

You also need to use `std::find` since `std::vector` doesn't provide a `.find()` member function.

Comment: I tried this but the STL doesn't provide a find member function for std::vector.

Comment: Aah, right,  you'll need `std::find`. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach which is similar in syntax to your Matlab:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> A = {1, 2, 3, -1, -2, 0, 0, 0, 4};
std::vector<int> B (A.begin(), A.end());
std::sort(B.begin(), B.end());
auto last = std::unique(B.begin(), B.end());
B.erase(last, B.end());
```

[Compiler explorer link](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:16,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:16,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:16,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:16),source:%27%23include+%3Calgorithm%3E%0A%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Ausing+namespace+std%3B%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++std::vector%3Cint%3E+A+%3D+%7B1,+2,+3,+-1,+-2,+0,+0,+0,+4%7D%3B%0A++++std::sort(A.begin(),+A.end())%3B%0A++++auto+last+%3D+std::unique(A.begin(),+A.end())%3B%0A++++A.erase(last,+A.end())%3B+%0A%0A++++for+(const+auto%26+i+:+A)%0A++++++++cout+%3C%3C+i+%3C%3C+endl%3B%0A%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:37.20695132096232,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_trunk,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:11,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B17%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:29.459715345704367,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:2,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%232+with+x86-64+clang+(trunk)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

If you want to find the indices for the locations of entries, you can use [`find_first_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find_first_of).